# Talk to Magento 2 REST API using Order Increment ID

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api

Is it possible to use the Order Increment on REST Endpoints in Magento 2 or do I have to call

https://example.com/rest/storeview/V1/orders?searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=increment_id&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=1000000001

or something similar before hand and read the entity_id field, in case I do only have the increment_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. For orders.

**UPD**. 
But you always can create your own api endpoint based on the increment id.